# Reading a csv file in, converting it to a 2-d array and then displaying it as a table on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have written a script to accept a csv file and then convert the csv file into a 2-dimensional array. I can see that the object i have saved it as is infact an array by using:

```
console.log(Array.isArray(data));
```

which returns true, and i can see its contents using

```
console.table(data);
```

I am now attempting to display the contents of the 2-d array as a html table on the webpage, here is what I have gotten so far:

```
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var row = {};
  var cell = {};

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = cellData;
    });
  });
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

called with

```
createTable(data);
```

I am receiving this error:

(index):69 Uncaught TypeError: rowData.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, so the problem must be with the data array.
Instead of console.table(data), do this:

```
console.log(data);
```

For let data = [ [1,3,5], [4,8,12] ]; the output is:

```
Array [ (3) […], (3) […] ]
​0: Array(3) [ 1, 3, 5 ]
​1: Array(3) [ 4, 8, 12 ]
​length: 2
​<prototype>: Array []
```

If what you are seeing is different, that should lead you to figuring out the problem.

Or ... reduce your code to this and see what you get:

```
tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    console.log(rowData); 
    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
         console.log(cellData);
    });
  });
```